# Camera source override on zoom

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, camera, zooming, video-conferencing

As we know the host has the liberty of disabling virtual-background on zoom,

i was thinking maybe we can take care of the problem by adding another "camera" that will output what we want - pictures! so now instead of people seeing what your camera shows, they will see the picture you put, this will also solve the headaches students have who want to appear as on the zoom while not being there - they can just make a gif of them naturally moving around, and this hack will work [the teacher wont pay attention at one out of 25 students that his eye blinks are on a loop :) ]

**if someone can develop a script for that - it will be a life savior for everyone!**

im not sure how the script will work either just interject the video input of the built-in camera or make another camera input available for this feature.. - and make sure it will be cross-platform ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a program named ["ManyCam"](https://manycam.com/), which functions as a webcam source in which you can set overlays, pictures and even GIF's and videos. The free version already offers a lot of these options I think.

This is would be my option at least.